# LAPACK/BLAS matrix multiplication in fortran returns zeros

Tags: fortran90, lapack

I'm a fortran beginner and simply wanted to try if i get a matrix multiplication to work.

```
    program testlapack
    implicit none

    COMPLEX, DIMENSION(2, 2) :: A, B, Output

    A = reshape((/ 4, 0, 0, 2 /), shape(A))
    B = reshape((/ 6, 0, 0, 3 /), shape(B))
    Output = reshape((/ 1, 0, 0, 1 /), shape(Output))

    call DGEMM('n','n',2,2,2,1.0,A,2,B,2,0.0,Output,2)

    Write(*,*) Output

    end program testlapack
```

I was expecting a simple A * B multiplication written into the Output-array. Instead, lapack is returning a 2x2 matrix with only zeros. The compilation with ifort -llpack yields no errors.

Where's my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that passing complex arguments to a subroutine expecting real arguments might be the cause of your problem.  Perhaps you meant to use `zgemm` rather than `dgemm` ?

Comment: This was certainly a good guess, and thanks. But it wasn't the only reason, the output has not changed :(

Answer (score 1):

I changed the matrices to REAL and used DGEMM. It worked once i used double precision for every number entering DGEMM, including the 1.0 set as "ALPHA". I didn't expect this to be mandatory.

Comment: That makes sense, given that the D in `DGEMM` means "double;" if you wanted single precision, you want the routine `SGEMM.`

Comment: Note that there's also `CGEMM` for complex numbers. [netlib documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/def/group__complex__blas__level3_gac4e11e8e8a4b0c802d2229b08da341f6.html#gac4e11e8e8a4b0c802d2229b08da341f6)